# CakePHP Form outside controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a login form in my header that talks to my users_controller but the form itself isn't in a view being generated by the users controller so I get two problems

1.) The password field doesn't get treat like a password field and is just a normal text field

2.) When submitting the form it just redirects to the login action

Here is the code and it's used in BOTH the login view and in my header (so I know it works):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array('id' => 'loginform', 'type' => 'post',
        'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'))); ?>

<fieldset id="login">

    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li id="li-username">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Username or email address')); ?>
        </li>
        <li id="li-password">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Password')); ?>
            <span id="iforgot"><?php echo $this->Html->link('?', 
            array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'forgotpassword'),  array('title' => 'Forgot your password?')); ?></span>
        </li>
        <li id="li-submit">
            <button type="submit" title="Log in">Log in &#9658;</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

</fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: jquery with ajax is best to perform this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not changing

> Form->create(null,...

to

> Form->create(**'User'**,...

otherwise change

> Form->input('username',...

to

> Form->input(**'User.username'**,...

Comment: I was having a problem where other Models were overriding a login form in my header. doing Form->input('User.username') instead of Form->input('username') fixed my problem. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use type = 'password'

```
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label'=>false, 'type' => 'password', 'placeholder'=>'Password'));
```

1. You have specified array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login') in your $this->Form->create() statement. So the form is submitted to "/users/login"

If you don't want to submit the form to '/users/login', you can use AJAX to perform login.

Hope these will answer your queries.